# What is the correct way to show 10000 maps/tiles on my contact address list web page?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I have a webpage with a grid of contact list (around 10K people).
I want to put in one of the columns a small map/tile of the address from a different column.
Do I need to generate 10k maps object and zoom to geocode address or is there an alternative solution to retrieve an image of the address coords and show it as a tile ?

Comment: OpenLayers and Google Maps can both handle many thousands of vectos (markers). But, I have to say, I'm not entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: @JohnBarça - I've rephrased my question